# Trouble in Frame by Frame Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am facing a problem in **Frame by Frame animation in Android**. Actually i am having lots of images as frames, for that i have crated different animation-list files for different animation. On the main screen i am having one background image on which i am having different buttons for different animation. I am done with animation also, but when i click 2nd time on the buttons the animation does not work. Means it is working only once. I don't why this is happening. Here is some code snippet of my project.

**Animation List File:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0000" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0001" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0002" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0003" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0004" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0005" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0006" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0007" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0008" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0009" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0010" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0011" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0012" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0013" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0014" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0015" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0016" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0017" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0018" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0019" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0020" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0021" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0022" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0023" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0024" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_angry0025" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

**Code:-**

```
ImageView rocketImage;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catlayout);

    rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundCat);
    rocketImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.angry_tail_animation);
}

public void headButtonClicked(View v) {
    final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mMailTab.getBackground();
    mMailTab.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if ( mailAnimation != null ) mailAnimation.start();
    }
    }); 
}
```

**headButtonClicked is a button placed by me for starting animation. It work only once. If anybody having any idea that how to resolve this problem please kindly help me.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your animation xml file you have added the attribute `android:oneshot="true"` which means you are wanting the Animation to be played only once. For playing it again you should make it  `android:oneshot="false"`

**UPDATE:**

If you want to start the Animation everytime you click the button you have to call the `animation.stop();` for the previous started Animation if Running. Something like this,

```
if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
         frameAnimation.stop();
      }

      else {
         frameAnimation.stop();
         frameAnimation.start();
      }
```

Comment: but i want this animation to be run on the button click, if i change oneshot to false then it is running for n time duration. I want that when user click on the button then only the animation should start and play. Again user clicks then play animation like that.

Comment: I am getting outofmemory error in this. Is there any other way to implement the Frame by Frame Animation because I try to search so many resources but i didn't get any solution for memory leak. Do you have any idea of it then please kindly let me know...

Comment: any idea on how to avoid outofmemory error? I'm on the same issue right now